# Snubber circuit protection

Tags: protection, snubber

I am trying to understand how to implement snubber circuit protection as I have seen different circuit diagrams, I am lost.

[image: snubber circuit schematics]

Image source: [Homemade Circuit Projects - Prevent Relay Arcing using RC Snubber Circuits](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/prevent-relay-arcing-using-rc-snubber-circuits/)

What is the right way to implement it — the number 1 or 2?

It's a 220 VAC power supply.

Comment: That depends if you are more interested in protecting the switch or leakage current when switch is off.

Comment: And yet a third possibility is to put the snubber across the input supply, as might be done to keep a refrigerator compressor from triggering a GFCI, without having to rewire the appliance. Refrigeration tripping GFCI is a common issue, often causing expense due to food spoilage.

Comment: Khales Naim - Hi, Please note the [site rule](/help/referencing) which requires that when a post includes content (e.g. text, image, photo etc.) copied or adapted from elsewhere, that content must be correctly referenced. As a minimum, for online material the source webpage or PDF etc. should be named & linked (see that rule regarding references for books / articles etc.). In order to help you, I found what I believe to be the source webpage link for the copied image & added it. For the future, please remember it's your responsibility to do that :) Thanks. (Please see the [tour] & [help].)

Answer (score 2):

We model mains as an impedance, usually with some equivalent inductance on the order of 100µH.  Most loads are at least a little inductive*, so add that to the loop as well.

*At short time scales; since mechanical contacts open extremely quickly, at least for the first tens of volts, this can apply as low as ~ns, where bare wires themselves look inductive.  Most "inductive" loads are inductive up to the ~ms time scale, such as transformers, motors and solenoids.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcGXF2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This basic model (also adding R3 for stability and C1 to show the ringing) gives a transient like this,

[image]

Notice both the mains side and the load side have inductive kick.

If we put an RC (\$R = \sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}\$, \$C_\textrm{snub} > 3 C_1\$ ) across the contacts, we dampen the loop:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiIipE.png)</sup>

[image]

The peak voltage is much lower, and it rings for fewer cycles.  But we allow some mains through -- the switch on/off ratio is worsened:

[image]

We can cure this by putting the snubber across the load, but then we leave the mains side undamped:

[...technical difficulties...]

[image]

Zoomed on the mains transient, magnified somewhat by increasing R3 to 1k for illustration.

The best of both worlds, is to put a large (bulk) capacitor across the mains -- usually a 0.1uF+ X1/X2 type (across-the-mains safety rated) capacitor -- closing the high-frequency loop around the switch and load.  This also provides a little EMI filtering, reducing emissions, in case that should be important.

Note that this capacitor can be any nearby capacitor, including capacitors that might be in power supplies or a line filter.

Comment: Seems I still can't create new schematics, but I can edit old ones successfully.  Guess I'll try again tomorrow...

Answer (score 0):

If the load is a 220VAC power supply, then the one on the left (the diagram is not labeled 1 or 2) or not bypassing the relay would be the correct way to do it.

If you did implement a series capacitor and resistor around the relay, it would leak residual AC current when the relay was turned off (capacitors pass AC current). So that would not be the way to go.

Comment: thanks a lot i see it more clear